# Comparing Pandas DF to a list of data objects

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
Region      City            Population
New York    New York City   8,335,897
New York    Hempstead town    393,375 
...
```

And I have a class and list of the instances for selection

```
@dataclass
class RegionCity:
    region: str
    city: str

region_city = []
region_city.append('New York', 'Hempstead town')
...
```

Is there a way to compare `region_city` list to the `Region` and `City` columns in Pandas? I tried:

`df.loc[lambda df: RegionCity(df['Region], df[City]) in region_city]`

but this gives this error:

`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

The examples I could find were comparing each column separately.

Thank you in advance

Comment: `region_city.append('New York', 'Hempstead town')` this gives an error. Is region_city supposed to be a list of tuples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that your `region_city` variable is a list of tuples, where the first element in each tuple is the region and the second element is the city.

Then, IIUC, what you essentially need is a merge or join operation on the 2 columns of Region and City to limit (or compare) your dataframe based on the entries in the `region_city` variable.

See code below:

```
# init
df =pd.DataFrame({'Region': ['New York', 'New York'], 'City': ['New York', 'Hempstead town'], 'Population': [8335897, 393397]})
region_city = []
region_city.append(('New York', 'Hempstead town'))

# change this init if you want to use your class instead of the variable region_city
reg, city = list(zip(*region_city))
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Region': reg, 'City': city})
df.merge(df2, on=['Region', 'City'], how='inner') # this will limit/compare your df to the list
```

Output:

```
     Region            City  Population
0  New York  Hempstead town      393397
```